# В чем ошибка? Почему не работает и как исправить?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет

Я пишу проект клиента и сервера, в Eclipse. Если я указываю локальный IP(192.168.1.100/127.0.0.1) - все нормально, но по внешнему ничего не получается. Вот такая ошибка вылетает в Server при попытке указать внешний адрес:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Server.<init>(Server.java:21)
at Main.main(Main.java:4)
```

Это код сервера:

```
public class Server {
private List<Connection> connections = 
        Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Connection>());
private ServerSocket server;

public Server() {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(Const.Port, 10, InetAddress.getByName("91.243.199.142"));
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Yes");
            Connection con = new Connection(socket);
            connections.add(con);
            con.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeAll();
    }
}

private void closeAll() {
    try {
        server.close();

        synchronized(connections) {
            Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                ((Connection) iter.next()).close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("!!");
    }
}
private class Connection extends Thread {
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private Socket socket;

    private String name = "";
    public Connection(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            name = in.readLine();
            synchronized(connections) {
                Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    ((Connection) iter.next()).out.println(name + " cames now");
                }
            }

            String str = "";
            while (true) {
                str = in.readLine();
                if(str.equals("exit")) break;

                synchronized(connections) {
                    Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext()) {
                        ((Connection) iter.next()).out.println(name + ": " + str);
                    }
                }
            }

            synchronized(connections) {
                Iterator<Connection> iter = connections.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    ((Connection) iter.next()).out.println(name + " has left");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
            connections.remove(this);
            if (connections.size() == 0) {
                Server.this.closeAll();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("!!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Вот проект клиента:

```
public class Client {
private BufferedReader in;
private PrintWriter out;
private Socket socket;
public Client() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите IP для подключения к серверу.");
    System.out.println("Формат: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

    String ip = scan.nextLine();

    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, Const.Port);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        System.out.println("Введите свой ник:");
        out.println(scan.nextLine());

        // Запускаем вывод всех входящих сообщений в консоль
        Resender resend = new Resender();
        resend.start();

        // Пока пользователь не введёт "exit" отправляем на сервер всё, что
        // введено из консоли
        String str = "";
        while (!str.equals("exit")) {
            str = scan.nextLine();
            out.println(str);
        }
        resend.setStop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        close();
    }
}

private void close() {
    try {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Потоки не были закрыты!");
    }
}

private class Resender extends Thread {

    private boolean stoped;

    public void setStop() {
        stoped = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!stoped) {
                String str = in.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Ошибка при получении сообщения.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Не могли бы подсказать в чем проблема? Буду очень признателен - долго уже ищу ответ, в интернете находил только локальное подключение..

Comment: Даниил, скорее всего Вы некорректно интерпретируете IP концепцию. Получается, что в Вашем случае у Вас есть IP адрес рабочей станции, например, это 192.168.0.104, на который вы можете производить bind (получить его можно, используя ipconfig команду в windows консоли. В то же время у Вас можем быть Ваш выделенный IP адрес, который Вам дал Ваш провайдер. Однако этот IP вашего роутера, а не рабочей станции. И поэтому для корректной работы порт приложения необходимо будет пробросить. Иными словами, чтобы понять, как Вам помочь, надо узнать откуда у Вас этот IP. Может это VPN, тогда дело в другом.

Comment: Если у вас приложение находится за NAT, то лучше использовать определение внешнего IP с помощью broadcast сервера, и при наличии маршрутизатора в маршруте правильно создавать для него правило, чтобы извне к вам могли подключиться. Пример библиотеки [тут](https://github.com/bitletorg/weupnp). При этом приложению не обязательно знать внешний IP адрес. Он не используется, в том виде, в каком вы его пытаетесь представить. Запуск приложения с биндом порта производится по локальному адресу машины.